# how do i call a method from of a service from activity which i started the service and reopened

Tags: android, android-activity, android-service

I have an activity and a service.
I want to start a countdown timer in the service and in the activity.

When I close the activity the timer in the service keeps on going in the background.

When I reopen the activity, I want to get the time remaining from the service's timer and start a new timer in the activity with the same time left. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: you can use Eventbus for communication between service and activity. https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus

Comment: Please post some code, showing what you tried and explain what errors or problems you ran into. It is difficult for people to give you a good quality answer otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Bad implementation. You are running service just to run a timer to show the remaining time when you restart the app?

Instead you can do the following.

If you are starting timer **now** for 5 minutes, then when you start the timer, take **`current system time in milliseconds`** and `add 5*60*1000`, that is, you are recording the time your timer should end and then store this long variable in `SharedPreference`.

Next time when you start your app, get the value of **finish time** from `SharedPreference` and subtract it from your current time again. This will directly give you the remaining time in milliseconds.

No Service, no background thread, no additional running code, just a shared preference in the beginning of the timer will keep the record for you.